# Freely movable container

Tags: positioning, environments

Is it possible to get an environment/container that is able to change the position of its content relative to the position where it would be normally. The content should be able to be anything like text or figures or (custom) environments. Someting would be great like:

```
\begin{container}[-5mm][-5mm][0mm]%expand 5mm to the top and to the left and 0mm to the right
\end{container}
```

The adjustwidth environment from the changepage package is close to that but it works only horizontally.

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by this, particularly "expand at the top". Can you be more precise?

Comment: I mean increasing the size of the area so that the margins become smaller and thus it would look like it was moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(10,50){... stuff ...}
\end{picture}
```

typesets `... stuff ...` offset by (10,50) (default units `pt`)

Comment: I already tried this but the problem was that using my custom figure macro with it (\put{10,50){\includefigure{pic}[MyLabel]}) resulted in errors like "Use of \put doesn't match its definition." "Missing \endgroup inserted." and others.

Comment: @user764754 `\put` takes an argument in parenthesis: you give an example where you have a `{` after `\put`, which would be a problem.

Comment: @user764754 as Joseph said, that should be `\put(10,50){\includegraphics{pic} more text}`

Comment: Oops, I meant to say \put(10,50){\includefigure...} causes those errors. I tried David Carlisle's solution with other custom macros which worked so I guess the problem is caused only by my \includefigure.